# Set region with rounded values/coordinates

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script, region, grass-7.0, grass-6.4

How do I set a region update with rounded coordinates.

I usually set my region from a puffer around my points of interest and round up the north and east coordinates and round down the south and west coordinates manually.

Is there a way to do that faster and automatically?

```bash
g.region vect=puffer
g.region -p
# output coordinates with decimal places, like:
# north:      5567793.38187444
# south:      5537794.12612555
# west:       3462339.95848376
# east:       3492338.47 
g.mapset mapset=PERMANENT
g.region n=5567794 s=5537794 w=3462339 e=3492339 res=30 -aps
g.mapset mapset=test
```

Comment: Do you mean `g.region -a` (for 'align')?

Comment: @countryman thats it! I should have looked in the documentation again... Add it as an answer and I'll accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the `g.region -a` (for 'align') option.

This will align the region to the resolution.